# How can I take heading and pitch in as arguments and return pixel placement in Google Street View?

Tags: javascript, google-street-view

The ultimate goal is to place an image on top of a Google Street View panorama that is consistently in one location on the panorama.

I want to take in heading/pitch as an argument and return an accurate pixel placement for an image, and anytime the panorama is moved, it should update to be in the same visual location.

How do I convert heading and pitch to (x, y) pixel placement?

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: @Roadowl - I updated the question, is there any more information you need?